# Remove all inline styles using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, inline

I'm doing some HTML cleaning with BeautifulSoup. Noob to both Python & BeautifulSoup. I've got  tags being removed correctly as follows, based on an answer I found elsewhere on Stackoverflow:

```
[s.extract() for s in soup('script')]
```

But how to remove inline styles? For instance the following:

```
<p class="author" id="author_id" name="author_name" style="color:red;">Text</p>
<img class="some_image" href="somewhere.com">
```

Should become:

```
<p>Text</p>
<img href="somewhere.com">
```

How to delete the inline class, id, name & style attributes of all elements?

Answers to other similar questions I could find all mentioned using a CSS parser to handle this, rather than BeautifulSoup, but as the task is simply to remove rather than manipulate the attributes, and is a blanket rule for all tags, I was hoping to find a way to do it all within BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't need to parse any CSS if you just want to remove it all. BeautifulSoup provides a way to remove entire attributes like so:

```
for tag in soup():
    for attribute in ["class", "id", "name", "style"]:
        del tag[attribute]
```

Also, if you just want to delete entire tags (and their contents), you don't need `extract()`, which returns the tag. You just need `decompose()`:

```
[tag.decompose() for tag in soup("script")]
```

Not a big difference, but just something else I found while looking at the docs. You can find more details about the API in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), with many examples.

Comment: I was using extract() in case I decided to generate a list of removed code at any point, but decompose() works just as well for completely removing & destroying tags & content. Thanks for the attribute-delete snippet, works like a charm!

Comment: Makes sense. I'll leave the note about `decompose()` for anyone else who might stumble across this.

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't do this in `BeautifulSoup` - you'll spend a lot of time trying, testing, and working around edge cases.

`Bleach` does exactly this for you.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach

If you were to do this in `BeautifulSoup`, I'd suggest you go with the "whitelist" approach, like `Bleach` does.  Decide which tags may have which attributes, and strip every tag/attribute that doesn't match.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about Bleach. I wasn't thinking of the use case, but if the goal is to sanitize untrusted HTML, then this definitely seems like a better approach. You get my upvote!

Comment: Bleach is pretty great.  I really like it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution for Python3 and BeautifulSoup4:

```
def remove_attrs(soup, whitelist=tuple()):
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        for attr in [attr for attr in tag.attrs if attr not in whitelist]:
            del tag[attr]
    return soup
```

It supports a whitelist of attributes which should be kept. :) If no whitelist is supplied all the attributes get removed.

Answer (score 2):

What about lxml's Cleaner?

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

content_without_styles = Cleaner(style=True).clean_html(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on jmk's function, i use this function to remove attributes base on a white list:

Work in python2, BeautifulSoup3

```
def clean(tag,whitelist=[]):
    tag.attrs = None
    for e in tag.findAll(True):
        for attribute in e.attrs:
            if attribute[0] not in whitelist:
                del e[attribute[0]]
        #e.attrs = None     #delte all attributes
    return tag

#example to keep only title and href
clean(soup,["title","href"])
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing mutable structures as default function parameter values. As seen [here](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but short:

```
' '.join([el.text for tag in soup for el in tag.findAllNext(whitelist)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using re and regex.

```
import re

def removeStyle(html):
  style = re.compile(' style\=.*?\".*?\"')    
  html = re.sub(style, '', html)

  return(html)

html = '<p class="author" id="author_id" name="author_name" style="color:red;">Text</p>'

removeStyle(html)
```

Output: <p class="author" id="author_id" name="author_name">Text</p>

You can use this to strip any inline attribute by replacing "style" in the regex with the attribute's name.